# Calling filter from different JS file in Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a controller that was residing in a separate file named as `EmployeeCtrl.js`. Inside this controller I have a filter called `convertJsonDate` to convert `JsonResult date format` to normal format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

My question now is, how do I make this filter reusable in different controller in the future? I have read that you can add your filter in a separate js file `filters.js` and inject it to your controller, but I don't know to implement this.

TIA

**app.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app', []);
})();
```

**EmployeeCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

app.filter('convertJsonDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, format) {
        return (input) ? $filter('date')(parseInt(input.substr(6)), format) : '';
    };
}]);

app.controller('app.EmployeeController', ['$scope', 'app.EmployeeService', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {

    GetAllEmployee();

    $scope.sortColumnBy = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }

    $scope.employee = {
        employeeId: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        password: '',
        daysPerWeek: 0,
        active: true,
        departmentId: 0,
        accountTypeId: 0
    };

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.employee.employeeId = '';
        $scope.employee.firstName = '';
        $scope.employee.lastName = '';
        $scope.employee.password = '';
        $scope.employee.daysPerWeek = 0;
        $scope.employee.active = false;
        $scope.employee.departmentId = 0;
        $scope.employee.accountTypeId = 0;
    };

    function GetAllEmployee() {
        var getEmployeeData = EmployeeService.getEmployees();

        getEmployeeData.then(function (employee) {
            $scope.employees = employee.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting employee records');
        });
    };  
}]);

})();
```

**Using convertJsonDate filter**

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="app.EmployeeController">
     .....
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="e in employees | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:searchKeyWord">
             <td>{{e.AccountDateExpired | convertJsonDate:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     ....
</div>
</div>
```

**Pastebin**

**Index.chtml**
http://pastebin.com/aXDSmYAV

**EmployeeCtrl.js**
http://pastebin.com/eQhRREPy

**app.js**
http://pastebin.com/1GB4uhvx

Comment: Filters can be used in the entire project. You can use in any template after once making it. are you talking about using it in the controller?

Comment: After placing `convertJsonDate` filter in a different JS file I'm receiving this error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: convertJsonDateFilterProvider <- convertJsonDateFilter`.

I also read one article in the web that you can use the filter directly in the controller instead of using it in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if they're in the same file or in different files. As long as both are in the same module, or the filter is in a module that you include in your dependencies, you will be able to use it.

I would suggest having 3 files here: one that declares your module, one for your controller(s), and one for your filter(s):

**module.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

**filters.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.filter('convertJsonDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, format) {
        return (input) ? $filter('date')(parseInt(input.substr(6)), format) : '';
    };
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('app.EmployeeController', ['$scope', 'app.EmployeeService', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {

    GetAllEmployee();

    $scope.sortColumnBy = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }

    $scope.employee = {
        employeeId: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        password: '',
        daysPerWeek: 0,
        active: true,
        departmentId: 0,
        accountTypeId: 0
    };

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.employee.employeeId = '';
        $scope.employee.firstName = '';
        $scope.employee.lastName = '';
        $scope.employee.password = '';
        $scope.employee.daysPerWeek = 0;
        $scope.employee.active = false;
        $scope.employee.departmentId = 0;
        $scope.employee.accountTypeId = 0;
    };

    function GetAllEmployee() {
        var getEmployeeData = EmployeeService.getEmployees();

        getEmployeeData.then(function (employee) {
            $scope.employees = employee.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting employee records');
        });
    };  
}]);

})();
```

Comment: Hi @JLRishe, I have created `filters.js` and put `convertJsonDate` filter in the `filters.js`. After running the website, I received this error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: convertJsonDateFilterProvider <- convertJsonDateFilter`

Comment: @klaydze Could you put your current attempt up on pastebin or something like that?

Comment: Please see my original post. I have attached the link as requested

Comment: Looks like I found the issue now. The solution is very simple yet always easy to overlooked. I just need to add my `filters.js` in the `BundleConfig.cs` in my project and after that it's working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

They can be reused  if you are using same app
...here,

```
var app = angular.module('app');
```

you could use this filter in the same way you are using it in current controller for any other controller under this app

Comment: What do you mean? The code above is for a module. What are you referring to as an `app` here? `ng-app` ?

Comment: The controllers that come under same app is what i meant

Comment: In angular we refer it as a `module`. There can be many sub-modules in an app, and the filter once register can be used anywhere. There can be nothing else than modules in the app.

Comment: Can you construct an example on how to do that?